# Split RDD into two RDD based on column in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Pyspark. I need to split RDD into two RDD based on id (column name) in Pyspark. One RDD should  contain duplicate values and another RDD should contain a non duplicates value.

Below are my input data looks like.

```
1,vikram,Technology,30000

2,vivek,Sales,20000

3,avnessh,Marketing,40000

5,Raju,Strategy,5000

1,mushahid,Sales,10000

3,Shyam,Legal,35000
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate with examples? What happens in case of first and fifth row?

Comment: first and fifth row will be in one RDD and rest of records should be in another RDD . as first and fifth is duplicate records as our key is id only

Comment: Can you include everything in the question? Will be helpful to all

Comment: can we use dataframe transformations, or is RDD transformation necessary?

Answer (score 1):

It's not mentioned if `RDD` transformations are necessary. So, I'm gonna go ahead and give an answer with `DataFrame` transformations. The resultant `DataFrame` can be converted to `RDD` if required (mentioned at the bottom).

Using a subset of your data

```
data = [
    [1,'vikram','Technology',30000],
    [2,'vivek','Sales',20000],
    [1,'mushahid','Sales',10000]
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF(['id', 'name', 'foo', 'bar'])

# +---+--------+----------+-----+
# | id|    name|       foo|  bar|
# +---+--------+----------+-----+
# |  1|  vikram|Technology|30000|
# |  2|   vivek|     Sales|20000|
# |  1|mushahid|     Sales|10000|
# +---+--------+----------+-----+

# count the "id" occurrances
id_counts = data_sdf.groupBy('id'). \
    agg(func.count('*').alias('id_cnt')). \
    filter(func.col('id_cnt') > 1)

dup_ids = [k.id for k in id_counts.collect()]
# [1]

# data with duplicate ids
dup_id_data_sdf = data_sdf. \
    filter(func.col('id').isin(dup_ids))

# +---+--------+----------+-----+
# | id|    name|       foo|  bar|
# +---+--------+----------+-----+
# |  1|  vikram|Technology|30000|
# |  1|mushahid|     Sales|10000|
# +---+--------+----------+-----+

# data with no duplicate ids
nodup_id_data_sdf = data_sdf. \
    filter(func.col('id').isin(dup_ids) == False)

# +---+-----+-----+-----+
# | id| name|  foo|  bar|
# +---+-----+-----+-----+
# |  2|vivek|Sales|20000|
# +---+-----+-----+-----+
```

To convert to `RDD`

```
dup_id_data_rdd = dup_id_data_sdf.rdd
nodup_id_data_rdd = nodup_id_data_sdf.rdd
```

Comment: However , for below statement in its giving me error
dup_ids = [k.id for k in id_counts.collect()]
Error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'collect'



following lib i am already imported
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

Comment: when i run id_counts.show() its giving me results as expected. its printing duplicates ids with count 


+---+-------+
| id|id_cnts|
+---+-------+
|  1|      2|
|  3|      2|
+---+-------+

Comment: do i need to convert this id_counts DF again to RDD ?

Comment: No you don't have to convert it to `RDD`. and what about `id_counts.collect()`? Does this give a result

Comment: id_counts.collect() ,giving me error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-168-ad4c3a80985d> in <module>
----> 1 dup_ids =id_counts.collect();

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'collect'

Comment: Thanks sankart its working , it was my mistake while assignment of id_counts , i given .show() action in end hence id_counts was not assigned hence dup_ids giving me nonetype object has no attribute error